# Div on top 100%

Tags: css-position, fixed

I try to put a div 100% on top of the content of the page. The problem comes when the content has some margin. I illustrate here with a simplified case.

If I understand, position fixed: "The element is positioned relative to the browser window". So,  why the div .trans is affected by what is behind? How to put the div transparent 100% of the page and on top of content?

Here is a good place to see the problem and try the solutions: http://jsfiddle.net/rdkAW/1/

CSS:

```
body { margin:0; }

.trans{
    position:fixed;
    width:100%; height:100%;
    margin:0;
    opacity:0.7; filter: alpha(opacity = 70);
    background-color:red;
    z-index:5;
}

#content {
    position:relative;
    margin:30px auto; /* is this the problem? */
    width:95%; max-width:890px; height:1200px;
    z-index:1;
    background-color:blue;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="trans"></div>
<div id="content"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved if I use. top:0; left:0; It seems that position fixed needs that. I still do not understand very well why. If the fixed div is 100% and by definition fixed position is relative to the window, why is it need to specify top and left? I would appreciate if someone can explain it.